# Unable to start namenode for hadoop (win7)

Tags: hadoop, installation

I've installed hadoop on windows, and now I'm getting an error when trying to format the namenode. What could be causing this?

```
   ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2044)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:452)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:591)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:613)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:188)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1206)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1649)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1759)
    2019-10-05 00:10:16,630 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and while provide some surrounding log entries while asking such questions

Comment: This error also applies to formatting the namenode, I'm actually having the same error and my hdfs-site locations are formatted correctly. Did you resolve this?

Comment: Hi Petro, I have resolved it by re-installing it several times, I think the error was due to incorrect specific java-home directory in hadoop.evs.cmd file.